# Qt Model/View: setRootIndex on a proxy model fails

Tags: qt

I have a tree model class that inherits `QAbstractItemModel` (let's say `Model`) and two filter proxy models inheriting `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Both proxy models are set on the same model instance:

```
m_groupFilter->setSourceModel(m_model);
m_parameterFilter->setSourceModel(m_model);
```

and these filters are set on two `QTreeView`s on UI:

```
ui->treeViewGroups->setModel(m_groupFilter);
ui->treeViewParameters->setModel(m_parameterFilter);
```

Now, I want to `setRootIndex()` of the second view, to the selected item from first one. Connecting signals and so on I do this:

```
QModelIndex actualIndex = m_groupFilter->mapToSource(index);
QModelIndex mappedIndex = m_parameterFilter->mapFromSource(actualIndex);
qDebug() << mappedIndex.isValid();
qDebug() << ui->treeViewParameters->model();
qDebug() << mappedIndex.model();
ui->treeViewParameters->setRootIndex(mappedIndex);
```

Above code fails with this output and a warning:

```
true
ConfigurationParameterFilterModel(0x43d190)
ConfigurationParameterFilterModel(0x43d190)
QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the currently set model
QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the currently set model
```

I can see that this only happens when models of input index for `setRootIndex` and the object calling `setRootIndex` on, differ (which is not the case here) or index is invalid (which is neither the case here). Following is the [Qt source code that generates the warning](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/3a569573b2b8e8dc56f0a152afcb48723b682ba8/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L1143) :

```
void QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (Q_UNLIKELY(index.isValid() && index.model() != d->model)) {
        qWarning("QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the currently set model");
        return;
    }
    d->root = index;
    d->doDelayedItemsLayout();
    d->updateGeometry();
}
```

So why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown is Ok. I copied it in the standard template project of Qt Creator. It worked properly. Check your proxy models implementation and the other places of `setRootIndex` calls.